# How to calculate the kinetic energy in field theory when the state is not vacuum state?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators

I have puzzles in calculating kinetic energy in the language of second quantization

As we know, the operator of kinetic energy is
$$\hat{H}=-\hat{\phi}^{\dagger}(x)\nabla^{2}\hat{\phi}(x)$$
where $\hat{\phi}(x)$ annihilates a particle at position x.

Suppose we have a state which is non-uniform in space
$$|\psi\rangle=\int dx f(\hat{\phi}(x),\hat{\phi}^{\dagger}(x))|0\rangle $$
where $ f(\hat{\phi}(x),\hat{\phi}^{\dagger}(x))$ is a function of $\hat{\phi}(x)$ and $\hat{\phi}^{\dagger}(x)$,

**My question is**
when we calculate $\langle\psi|\hat{H}|\psi\rangle$, we need to calculate

$\langle\psi|(-\hat{\phi}^{\dagger}(x)\nabla^{2}\hat{\phi}(x))|\psi\rangle $ or $\langle\psi|-\hat{\phi}^{\dagger}(x)(\nabla^{2}\hat{\phi}(x)|\psi\rangle)$?

**If the former is right**, could we put the $\nabla$ out of the braket:
$\langle\psi|(-\hat{\phi}^{\dagger}(x)\nabla^{2}\hat{\phi}(x))|\psi\rangle $=$\nabla^{2}\langle\psi|(-\hat{\phi}^{\dagger}(x)\hat{\phi}(x))|\psi\rangle $?

Answer (score 0):

Note that your Hamiltonian should actually be a Hamiltonian density with $H = \int dx \mathcal{H}(x)$. The energy is then: $$ \langle{\psi|H|\psi}\rangle = \int dx \langle{0}| f(\phi(x),\phi^\dagger(x))^\dagger \int dy (-\phi^\dagger(y) \nabla_y^2 \phi(y) ) \int dz f(\phi(z),\phi^\dagger(z)) |{0}\rangle= \int dx dy dz\langle{0}| f(\phi(x),\phi^\dagger(x))^\dagger (-\phi^\dagger(y) \nabla_y^2 \phi(y) ) f(\phi(z),\phi^\dagger(z)) |{0}\rangle.$$

For $\langle\psi|\mathcal{H}(x)|\psi\rangle$, you can do the same calculation, but in this case you do not integrate over $x$ (which was called $y$ in above equation).

Overall, this implies that you **cannot** pull $\nabla_y^2$ out of the bracket, however (if you want) you could use partial integration to rewrite $\phi^\dagger(y) \nabla^2 \phi(y) = \nabla(\phi^\dagger \nabla \phi) - (\nabla \phi^\dagger) (\nabla \phi)$, where the parenthesis indicate on which objects nabla acts.

Comment: Thanks for your answe. From your anser, we could see the kinetic energy is not the Laplacian operator acting on the two-point correltaion function. If the state is a gaussian state, which is fully described by the mean-value  M (x) of the annihilation operator and two-point corrlation function G(x,x'), then how should we express its kinetic energy in terms  of the M(x) and G(x,x').